# This loss/defeat shouldn't really affect them

Tags: word-usage

When I'm talking about "losing a match",  will it be okay to use "loss" to mean "defeat"?  Like a team wins all the matches in a row and loses a match (but not in the end), will it be okay to use:

> This loss shouldn't really affect them.

Or should it be:

> This defeat shouldn't really affect them.

I guess only the second sentence sounds right.  Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: Yes, "loss" is synonymous with "defeat".

Comment: So is it  natural @Andrew?

Comment: I would use "loss" because "defeat" has a stronger connotation and the intent seems to be to minimize the feeling.

Comment: Yes, it's natural, but which you use depends on the context.  As @RonJensen says, "defeat" can sound *stronger*, and you might not want to make the other person feel bad about it.